# Output array as nested divs

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have an array which I want to output as nested divs. There is a bit of a bug with it but I cannot work out where the HTML problem is.

I want the data to output as:

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="item">Data comes out here</div>
   <div class="item">Data comes out here</div>
   <div class="item">Data comes out here</div>
```

But at present there is an extra `item` div wrapping everything and so my HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
       <div class="item">Data comes out here</div>
       <div class="item">Data comes out here</div>
       <div class="item">Data comes out here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can't work out how to adjust the array output to not output in the first `item` div and instead output `item` divs *within* the `container` div

[**Live example**](http://www.sagittarius-digital.com/sag-aggregator/sag-aggregator.html)

Code:

```
jQuery(function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: 'http://www.sagittarius-digital.com/news.rss', /* source */
          dataType: 'xml'
        }).done(function(xml){
          var items = $(xml).find('item').map(function(){
                var $item = $(this);
                var array = '<div class="item">';
                array += '<a href="' + $item.find('link').text() + '">';
                array += '<h2>' + $item.find('title').text() + '</h2>';
                array += '<p>' + $item.find('description').text() + '</p>';
                /* Outputs date as YYYYMMDD */
                var date     = new Date( $item.find('pubDate').text() );
                var yyyymmdd = date.getFullYear() +''+ (date.getMonth()+1) +''+ date.getDate();
                array += '<p>' + yyyymmdd + '</p>';
                array += '<p>Category: ' + $item.find('category').text() + '</p>';
                array += '</a>';
                array += '</div>';
                return array;
          }).get();
          $('div.item').append(items.join(' '));
        }).fail(function(){
          console.log('error', arguments)
        })
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this line cause the current behavior :

```
$('div.item').append(items.join(' '));
```

Try changing to this:

```
$('div.item').after(items.join(' '));
```

Instead of inserting inside the div, it will be inserted right after.

Answer (score 0):

Use .after instead of .append, like this:

```
$('div.item').after(items.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of  `$('div.item').append(items.join(' '));`use

```
 $('#container').append(items.join(' '));
```

because it'll append an extra `item` class division.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(xml).find('item').each(function(index,element)
{
    var item = $('<div class="item"></div>');
    var link = item.append('<a href="'+$(element).find("link").text()+'"></a>')
    link.append("<h2>"+ $(element).find("title").text() + "</h2>");
    link.append("<p>"+ $(element).find("description").text() + "</p>");

    //Suggestion: use moment.js :P
    var date     = new Date( $(element).find("pubDate").text() );
    var yyyymmdd = date.getFullYear() +''+ (date.getMonth()+1) +''+ date.getDate();

    link.append("<p>"+yyyymmdd+"</p>");
    link.append("<p>Category: "+$(element).find("category").text()+"</p>");

    item.appendTo("#container")
});
```

Better way, it should work :)